# Count how many table entries have been made per day via MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table for every event on my website called event_archive.
I can count how many events have been registered with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_archive
WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59';
```

Is there any way to show how many entries have been made per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by for get a count for day

```
SELECT date(event_time) , COUNT(*) 
FROM event_archive
WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
group by  date(event_time)
```

and you can build the date using date() function

Answer (score 1):

Yes by using the GROUP BY and the DATE() function

```
SELECT DATE(event_date) as theDate, COUNT(*) 
FROM event_archive
WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE(event_time)';
```